# sforce.one.createRecord in LEX Unable to save the record

Tags: visualforce, lightning, custom-button, lightning-experience, list-button

I am trying to create a related list button with default values with sforce.one, however when I try to click Save button I am getting this error "Review the errors on this page". But no errors listed, and all the required fields have been filled properly.

VF page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" recordSetVar="opps">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/28.0/connection.js"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/28.0/apex.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
                sforce.connection.sessionId = "{!$Api.Session_ID}";
                $( window ).ready(function() {            
                    createOpportunity();
                });

    var recordId = '{!$CurrentPage.parameters.Id}';
    var OBJECT_NAME_HERE ='Opportunity';
    var RECORDTYPE_NAME_HERE ='Internship Seats';
    var url  ='/006/e?retURL=%2F&'


    try{ 
        //Query the record type
        var RecordTypeIds = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType='" + OBJECT_NAME_HERE + "' AND Name='" + RECORDTYPE_NAME_HERE + "' LIMIT 1");
        var rtTypes= RecordTypeIds.getArray("records");
        var RecordTypeId = rtTypes[0].Id;

        //Query the parent record
        var cons = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id,Name FROM Account WHERE Id = '" + recordId + "'");
        var stats= cons.getArray("records");

        //Internship Seats Opportunity
        url +='RecordType='+RecordTypeId;
        url +='&CF00N50000001oGFd='+stats[0].Name;
        url +='&CF00N50000001oGFd_lkid='+stats[0].Id;
        url +='&opp11=Open';      

        //Default values
        var defaultValues = {            
            'AccountId':stats[0].Id,  
            'Corporate_Account__c' : stats[0].Id,
            'StageName':'Open',
            'retURL':'/006',
            'nooverride':'1'
        }

        } 
    catch(e){ 
        alert('An Error has Occured. Error:' +e); 
    }

    function createOpportunity(){

        if( (typeof sforce != 'undefined') && sforce && (!!sforce.one) ) { 
            sforce.one.createRecord('Opportunity',RecordTypeId,defaultValues);
        }else{
            window.location='{!URLFOR($Action.Opportunity.New, null, [RecordType='+RecordTypeId+',save=1], true)}';           
        }

    } 

    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it worked after removing this " 'retURL':'/006',
            'nooverride':'1'"